# Gnome shell two monitors full screen apps

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gnome-shell, gnome-3

I'm working on the Ubuntu 16.04 whit Gnome Shell version 3.18.5 and I'm using two monitors. Issue which I have regarding aplications opend in the full screen mode.
For expample if I open on the monitor number 1 my browser and on the monitor number 2 terminal in full screen mode plus some additional application such as a code editor(not full screen). Now when I'm focus on the code editor which is on the top of the terminal it's ok but when I click on my broser window(monitor 1) then the code editor gose behind the terminal automatically.

I've prepared some video to better show this problem:

- In this [video you can see correct behaviour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KcevXZ3qm8&feature=youtu.be) when I'm using one monitor.
- Here is [video showing incorrect behaviour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X67WN8FRSHQ&feature=youtu.be). Don't care about the elements which are above the terminal on the left screen. Terminal was set to full screen.

Dose anybody know how to change this behaviour? I was looking for solution in google but without success. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

That's the expected behavior when things are in focus/out of focus.  Try resizing your windows so they don't block one another; thus, nothing will be "behind" anything else when you shift focus by clicking here or there.

Comment: Maybe that's the expected behavior but definitely not comfortable. In my opinion the window should be on the top only if it's set to show on top or is focused not when I click on complitly diffrent window on the other monitor. In windows it works perfect.

Comment: What is worth to add is a fact that the issue is appear only when I'm using more then one monitor.